# Why are modules only working in the shell inmy django app

Tags: python, django, shell, twitter, module

I am importing modules in my django app to use twitter. Modules like twitter, twython, tweepy etc. This is the path showed when I pip uninstall twitter

```
/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

but when i look there in the site packages there is no twitter. Where are my packages? Something told me to try the pyshell, so I fire it up and did this

```
import twitter
print(twitter)
# my output
<twitter.api.Twitter object at 0x10410b940>
```

Why can the shell access it but not my django app?

Comment: Did you include it in the APPS list in settings.py?

Comment: @joelgoldstick yes I did even tho it doesn't mention it in the docs, I did I even deactivtted my environ and started it again still nothing

Comment: That's a clue.  The directory you list is not in your environment.  Are you using virtualenv? or virtualenvwrapper?  If so, look in your project for .virtualenv directory, or wherever you set it up for virtualenvwrapper. You need to install it (pip?) while in the virtual env

Comment: @joelgoldstick I'm using virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

@joelgoldstick I am in the environment when I install. I figured it out tho. sorta. I had to hover over it with my mouse and click install twitter. I have never had to do that ever. Glad I learned that, now I know for the future. But I still do not see it in my directories. It must be a pycharm thing